# Connecting to FritzBox NAS using cifs

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, 22.04, samba

I'm trying to mount to my Fritz.box NAS. I can browse through the folder using Nautilus and read it. When trying to copy any files the progress bar starts, but there's no actual progress.

A `touch ./bla.txt` results in `No such file or directory`  and `sudo touch ./bla.txt` results in a `permission denied`
`cp` gives no output and `sudo cp` also throws a `permission denied`.

This is my connection string:

```
//fritz.box/fritz.nas/Western_Digital   /mnt/fritz    cifs  username=user,password=pass,domain=WORKGROUP,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=2.0,noserverino,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,nounix 0 0
```

I found that `noserverino` is recommended to handle the Stale File error which happens often at Fritz.box NAS.

This is my `id`:

```
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare),999(docker)
```

I have executed: `sudo chown user:user /mnt/fritz`

What am I missing in my setup?

Comment: You could try `smbclient` from the command line with a suitably high debug level, to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: do have an ip address for the Fritz box and a share set up for it? I access my NAS in fstab by addressing it from its ip address //192.168.1.nnn/<share_name> for example and a corresponding directory in /media (such as /media/NAS/<share_name>.

Comment: I have used an ip address as well. This doesn't make a difference in how it behaves.

Comment: Anything I should look for @Jos? There's quite a lot of output when doing: `smbclient -L \\192.168.1.118 -d 10`

Comment: You set the debug level to the highest :-) perhaps take it down a little (the default is 1) and look for obvious errors and warnings. Sorry, I can't be any more specific.

Answer (score 0):

maybe he can help you:
//fritz.box/fritz.nas/Western_Digital  /mnt/fritz  cifs  auto,vers=3.0,noserverino,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,username=n{your username},password={your password},file_mode=0776,dir_mode=0776  0  0

documentation:
https://www.andwil.de/weblog/linux-fritznas-mounten-cifs

Comment: I’m not sure that’s going to help much - the link is to a German site. Can you try to explain a bit more?